# Generics and inheritance in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a tiny problem using (what I assume are) generics. I have this code:

```
public class A{
  private String name;

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
 }
}


public class B extends A{
  private String street;

  public String getStreet(){
    return this.street;
 }
}

public class C extends A{
  private int number;

  public int getNumber(){
    return this.number;
 }
}
```

And I'd like to create new classes that will look like this :

```
public class AChange{
  private A instance;

  public String doSomething(){
    return A.getName();
 }
}

public class BChange extends AChange{

  public String street(){
    return A.getStreet();
 }
}

public class CChange extends AChange{

  public int number(){
    return A.getNumber();
 }
}
```

And of course, A class doesn't have those methods, but the subclasses do. How can I write this code, so it will work the way I want it to?

Comment: May be use something like `<? super A>` in Your generics?

Comment: And where have you hidden the generics?

Comment: Why does not BChange extends B and CChange extends C?

Comment: The use of generics is very limited. Like tafa says, `BChange extends B` or a plain wrapper around `B` is simpler and does not have all the issues you can have with generics such as exploding complexity, rawtypes, erasure, ..

Comment: Given this code it may be simpler, but in my case it's more complicated, so I decided that would make the code easier to maintain, but perhaps I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a generic type parameter to `AChange` to be used as type of field `instance`:

```
class AChange<T extends A> {
    protected T instance;

    public String doSomething() {
        return instance.getName();
    }
}
```

and define it in `BChange` and `CChange` accordingly

```
class BChange extends AChange<B> {
    public String street() {
        return instance.getStreet();
    }
}

class CChange extends AChange<C> {
    public int number() {
        return instance.getNumber();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same without generics like so

```
static class AChange {
    private A instance;
    public AChange(A instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public String doSomething() {
        return instance.getName();
    }
}

static class BChange extends AChange {
    private B instance;
    public BChange(B instance) {
        super(instance);
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public String street() {
        return instance.getStreet();
    }
}

static class CChange extends AChange {
    private C instance;
    public CChange(C instance) {
        super(instance);
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    public int number() {
        return instance.getNumber();
    }
}
```

Instead of using a generic instance `T`, store a reference of the right type